# Is this edit correct?

Tags: discussion, edits

I just closed a question as it was no where linked to a programming question. However I just opened the question again to track the update and found that the question tag(from `function` tag to `motion planning`) was edited.

I can understand the function tag as it was from a new user who might not be aware about the site's working.

But the motion planning tag was from a user who has a good reputation and must be aware about the site's working.

Here is the [question revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34649924/revisions)

I have even clicked on the `delete` button to remove the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649924/where-is-the-right-place-for-family-holidays-in-costa-rica).

So my question is what should one do in such situation? Or is deleting the question completes our responsibility?

Comment: Bahahaha, hilarious :)  No, we are not allowed to have fun.   Lighten up please.

Comment: That question reeks of SPAM setup. They posted a variation at SU: http://superuser.com/questions/1022940/i-want-to-purachase-a-small-part-of-pureto-viejo-property-can-anyone-help-me

Comment: @mat can you post a screenshot for us non-10k users?

Comment: @Magisch: there's nothing interesting in it. The Q on SO was about finding a good location for a family vacation in Costa Rica. The one on SU about finding an ideal residence there...

Comment: As for that poster, "Tell me why I shouldn't get rid of you." Why did SO not tell him "You're fired!"?